# What are the exact calculations in this hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Can anybody explain how this number has been calculated as the correct number?

Testing $H_0: p=0.4$ against $H_1: p<0.4$ with $n=11$ trials
at significance level $5\%:$

Number of successes: $X=2.$

One tailed $5\%$, tail probability = $0.05.$

And the answer is $P(X\le2)=0.1189.$

I would appreciate it a lot if anybody can explain how 0.1189 is calculated with details. And what is the process called?

Comment: What test was performed?

Comment: hint, in R `pbinom(2,prob=0.4,size=11)` = 0.1189.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Comments* on finding the P-value of this test and on the poor power of this test.

**P-value: Exact binomial computation.** @BenBolker's hint shows how to get the *exact* P-value $0.1189$ of the test using R to compute
the probability of getting 2 or fewer successes under the null hypothesis---that the observed number of successes $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=11, p=.4).$
That is, $P(X \le 2\,|\,n=11,p=0.4) = 0.1189.$ [In R, the function `pbinom` is a binomial CDF.]

```
pbinom(2, 11, .4)
[1] 0.1189168
```

---

*Addendum per comment:* You can get this answer from the from the PDF formula of the binomial distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n=11, p=.4).$ With $n=11$ and $p =0.4,$ you seek
$P(X \le 2) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2).$

The formula is
$P(X = k) = {11 \choose k}(0.4)^k(1-0.4)^{11-k},$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots, 11.$

In particular, $P(X=1) = {11\choose 1}(0.4)(0.6)^{10} = 11(.4)(0.006046618) = 0.02660512,$ which you might round to $0.0266.$

Using ${11\choose 0} = 1,$ you can find $P(X=0) = (1)(.4)^0(.6)^{11} = (0.6)^{11} = 0.0036.$

Similarly, $P(X = 2) = {11 \choose 2}(.4)^2(.6)^9 = 0.0887,$ because
${11\choose 2}=\frac{11!}{2!\cdot 9!} = \frac{110}{2} = 55.$

Finally,
$P(X \le 2) = 0.00363 + 0.02660 + 0.08868 = 0.1189.$

```
11*.4*.6^10
[1] 0.02660512
dbinom(1,11,.4)
[1] 0.02660512

.6^11
[1] 0.003627971
dbinom(0,11,.4)
[1] 0.003627971

(110/2)*.4^2*.6^9
[1] 0.08868372
dbinom(2,11,.4)
[1] 0.08868372
choose(11, 2)
[1] 55

0.00363 + 0.02660 + 0.08868
[1] 0.11891
sum(dbinom(0:2,11,.4))
[1] 0.1189168
pbinom(2, 11, .4)
[1] 0.1189168
```

---

**Normal approximation to binomial is not exact.** You may have been accustomed to using a normal approximation to the binomial
distribution to get P-values for binomial tests. To do that, you would begin by standardizing.

Standardize to get $Z = \frac{2 = np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} = -1.447,$
assume that $Z$ is standard normal, and thus obtain
$P(X \le 2) \approx P(Z \le -1.447) = 0.0698 \ne 0.1189.$
[If you use a continuity correction, you get a better
approximation: $P(X \le 2) = P(X \le 2.5)$ $\approx P(Z \le -1.1694) =$ $0.1211.$]

```
n=11;  p=.4
mu = 11*.4;  mu
[1] 4.4
sd = sqrt(11*.4*.6); sd
[1] 1.624808
z = (2-mu)/sd; z
[1] -1.477098
pnorm(z)
[1] 0.0698247
zc = (2.5-mu)/sd; zc  # continuity correction
[1] -1.169369
pnorm(zc)
[1] 0.1211275
```

This approximate method does not give
an accurate answer for your test because $n$ is not quite large enough to use a normal approximation. [One rule is to use the normal approximation only if both $np$ and $n(1-p)$ exceed 5. Then you can expect about two decimal points of accuracy, if $p$ is not too far from $1/2.]$

**Significance level of the test.** A test at exactly the 5% level would require randomization. Under $H_0,$ we
have $P(X \le 2) = 0.1189$ and $P(X \le 1) = 0.03.$ So a test at (about) the 3%
level of significance rejects if the observed number $X$ of Successes is 1 or fewer.

```
pbinom(1, 11, .4)
[1] 0.03023309
```

**Power of the test.** Using $n = 11$ trials to test this hypothesis is not only too small to use a
normal approximation. It is also too small to give good power. Power is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when it is false.

For example,
if the true success probability were $p = 0.2,$ then using the criterion
to reject for $X \le 1,$ the probability of rejecting $H_0$ is only about $0.3221 \approx 32\%.$ So for many practical purposes, testing $H_0$ with only $n=11$ trials
is not a good idea.

```
pbinom(1, 11, .2)
[1] 0.3221225
```

**Using more trials for better power.** By contrast, if we were to use $n = 50$ trials, then a test that rejects
for $X \le 13$ is at about the 3% level, and the power against the
alternative $p = 0.2$ is $0.8894$ or almost $89\%.$

```
pbinom(13, 50, .4)
[1] 0.02798836       # Significance level
pbinom(13, 50, .2)
[1] 0.8894135        # Power against p=0.2
```

Comment: We cannot do the calculations needed to get 0.1189? I mean why we should always give it to R or other programs to do that? Is not possible to do calculations ourselves?

Comment: You can do it by using the binomial formula, which you can find in almost any probability book. This is pretty clearly a 'self study' problem, for which you did not follow the directions on this site to **show what you have tried.** That makes it very difficult for us to know exactly what level of help you need. I will put some further details into my answer.